# Flex in Eclipse without Flex Builder/FDT

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have used before flashdevelop, but since i want to code java i find it convenient to have both worlds in one ide. However, it seems that without flex builder you cannot do that, and FDT looks like only works for air or haxe/flash. So, is there a workaround?

Comment: FDT works with Flex alright.

Comment: Also, check out IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @RIAstar without adobe's plugin? How is that? It lets you import classes? autocomplete and stuff?

Comment: Yes, it does everything FlashBuilder (Adobe's plugin) does, and more. You might want to read this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918992/is-flash-builder-for-flex-also-open-source/13919211#13919211